# Can one practice their Leining on Tisha Be'av?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, tisha-bav

One cannot learn Torah on Tisha Be'av. Is practicing one's leining considered 'learning'? 
To an extent if one understands the words one's saying automatically one will have learnt Torah.

Comment: For the record, one doesn't need to understand the words he's saying to fulfill the Mitzvah of learning Torah. He fulfills a Mitzvah of Talmud Torah by simply saying words of Torah even without any understanding (of course, it's a greater Mitzvah to understand the words, but no understanding is a Mitzvah nonetheless).

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? It might just be me who misunderstood, but I first read the question as 'can someone practice Leining on Tishah B'Av, i.e. any Leining, as it's routine reading', but it seems like other people are reading it as 'can the Bal Korei practice the Tishah Ba'v Laining'. It could just be me totally misunderstanding it.

Comment: I didn't specify which leining. I meant it in general.

Comment: @Salmononius2 see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/study-of-written-law-without-comprehension which addresses the point directly. In the answers there the earliest explicit source for this is 18th century. I don't think it is at all clear that this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one may practice the readings for Tisha b'Av. See [Shulchan Arukh OC 554:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93_%D7%93) and the commentaries there.

Comment: As I understood the M"B, while anyone may review the morning reading (which is specifically relevant to the day), only a person who might be *leining* should practice the afternoon reading. (Additionally, the Taz allows reviewing part of the weekly Torah portion, if a person is accustomed to doing that daily).

Comment: @Fred That is the (bizarre) simple read. So should we derive from this that everyone besides the reader should also space-out / cover their ears during leining at Mincha? Why is something permitted for some people and not others?

Comment: DoubleAA I happen to agree with @Fred here, and it's in line with what my Rabbi said when I asked if I could practice Leining on Tishah B'Av. As per everyone else listening to the Leining, I would say that falls under the category of the 'Davening routine', which if you look 2 Mishnah Berurahs earlier, he seems to feel the need to explain is permitted, as some might have made that assumption that one indeed should 'cover their ears' or the like for those parts of Davening.

Comment: @Salmononius2 And are you not supposed to have kavana when you daven? If you're saying it you can understand it and think about it. This is generally called "learning".

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, and the fact that the Mechaber and Mishnah Berurah have to point out that it's permitted seems to imply that it's somewhat of a chidush to allow one to daven those parts on Tishah B'Av. To say that also allows one to learn (even the same pieces) at other times I don't think would be a fair conclusion.

Comment: @Salmononius2 To learn them _more_ than one would at davening, I understand. I'm talking about learning at the same level.

Comment: Downvoter, what is incorrect about this answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA The way I'm understanding what you're saying (and please correct me if I'm misunderstanding you), is one could learn Torah all day by reading parts of the Torah in a 'Davening' manner (for arguments sake, we'll say the piece is indeed a part of Davening, i.e. Shema). If that's the case, why does the Mishnah Berurah (Sif 8)  specify that the Chazzan could practice the reading, anyone should?

Comment: @DoubleAA During the Torah reading, the congregation can and should listen and pay attention since it is part of *seder hayom*. Seemingly according to the Ramban, this was excluded from the original decree preventing Torah study on Tisha B'Av ([*Toras HaAdam*, *Aveilus Y'shana*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41324&st=&pgnum=137)). (However, I didn't downvote).

Comment: And for the record, I'm not the downvoter. I happen to agree with your answer, it's the comments I'm arguing about. And as an aside, I usually don't downvote (except in extreme cases), as it's not worth losing a point of my own over a downvote ;) I actually upvoted your answer, as I agree with that part.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I agreed with you that the simple read of the MB is odd. Hence you shouldn't read too much into it, and indeed anyone could practice the reading and אורחא דמילתא נקט

Comment: @DoubleAA The only thing unusual about the MB (IMHO) is that, like the Magein Avraham, the MB seems to read the Rama's words differently from they seem to mean on the surface. The Taz seems to fit better with the Rama, IMHO. But I don't think the MA and MB have an untenable position in and of itself.

Comment: @DoubleAA It seems your objections to the simple understanding of the Mishnah Berurah are A) how are other people allowed to listen and B) why can the Chazzan read it and no one else. A can be answered by saying it's part of the Seder Hayom. As for B, I'm saying "Ein Hachi Nami" (spelling?) you're right, the rule is different for the Chazzan. Off the top of my head, I don't think it's unreasonable to say he's given a special permission for the sake of Kavod Hatzibur, not embarrassing himself, etc.

Comment: @Salmononius2 To say it's a Heter of Kavod Hatzibbur is quite the Chiddush! That means he should lechatchila avoid ever getting in such a situation and practice entirely beforehand. Do you have evidence of that?

Answer (score 1):

One is not allowed to practice reading from the Torah on Tishah B'Av, even if he doesn't understand the words he's saying (i.e. just 'thoughtlessly' reading and memorizing the words).

As @DoubleAA pointed out, the exception to this would be the one reading the Torah in Shul would be allowed to practice it in advance. (I'm making my own conclusion here, but I would assume that even if one hasn't officially 'signed up' to be the reader in Shul for Tishah B'Av but there's a possibility he'll end up reading, he'll also be able to practice in advance)

Source: I thought a couple years back that I had a great day to practice laining, as I had off from work and didn't want to do any taxing physical labor. However, when I asked my Rabbi, he told me I was mistaken. Also, the way I'm understanding [Shulchan Arukh OC 554:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%93_%D7%93) and accompanying Mishnah Berurahs seems to agree with this answer.

Comment: Source for your first sentence? It seems incorrect. There is no Simcha in that.

Comment: The source in my third paragraph I believe covers all the points I suggested. It seems that there's an inherent Simcha in things that are Talmud Torah, regardless of if it seems 'boring or monotonous' at the moment. The exception would be things that are specifically 'depressing' (i.e. those pieces that are allowed to be learnt on Tishah B'Av, Eichah, etc), the Simcha of Talmud Torah is 'overruled'.

Comment: I don't see how the source in your third paragraph relates at all to your first sentence or to your claim in the comment. It just lists certain permitted things.

Comment: The part of the source where I asked my Rabbi was specifically about Leining, so it covers my first sentence. And based on the way I'm understanding the Mishnah Berurah (as per the various comments), it agrees with the ruling. I specifically left my comment about Simcha in the comments, as that was my own conjecture, but that was me merely trying to explain why I think the Mechaber/Mishnah Berurah ruled like they did.

Comment: I'm guessing, based on your skills at reading rabbinic sources, that when you practice your laining you understand what you read. I further guess your rabbi knew that. Thus I am unclear how you derive your first sentence from your rabbi's response. Are they details of his response of which I am unaware?